# Excel Formula - Conditional SUM exact match two columns row to row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Hi,

Hope someone can help me. I am trying to SUM column B/Column C/Column D like the results below. (15/9/12)

The condition is: Based on the row data of Column A, if the same row in Column B matches Column A (i.e. A3=B3, A4=C4), then it should SUM the matched rows for the column.

Same thing for Column C. Only the red data is matches Column A (1+3+5), Sum result should be 9.

Without add any additional columns for comparing data to match or not, is there anyway I can sum this?

Tried SUMIF or INDEX MATCH but since it needs to be exact match row to row (cell to cell), I can't think of any other options. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B6*(B2:B6=$A$2:$A$6))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`=MMULT(TOROW(A2:A6),N(B2:D6=A2:A6))`

[image]

TOROW could be replaced with TRANSPOSE in Excel 2021

Answer (score 0):

```
=BYCOL(B3:D7,LAMBDA(c,SUM(FILTER(c,c=A3:A7))))
```

[image: Picture Reference]